# Extract a specific combination from all possible combinations in R

Tags: r, vector, combinations, combn

Given the following vector of length `n=10`:

```
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
vec <- c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)
```

Suppose we want to apply the operator `&` to all possible combinations of the vector elements. That is:

```
res <- combn(n, 2, function(v) vec[v[1]]&vec[v[2]])
# total number of possible combinations is n(n-1)/2 = 45
```

However, we know that the result of `&` operator is true only when both values are `1` and hence, we can do it in a more clever way. In fact, the result of `combn` is a vector of length `45` with only one value of `1` and the rest are just `0`.

Now the question is that how we can extract the position of the only `1` without applying the `combn` itself? Once we can get it, we generate the result simply as follow:

```
res <- rep(0, 45)
res[index] <- 1
```

where `index` is the questioned position.

Comment: How is `n` in the `combn` function defined?

Comment: @Procrastinatus Maximus: `n = 10` in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (assuming that only two positions of the vector are 1, rest are zeros):

```
vec <- c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)

n <- length(vec)
pos <- which(vec==1)
index = ifelse(pos[1]==1, 0, sum((n-1):(n-pos[1]+1))) + (pos[2] - pos[1])
index
#[1] 38

res <- combn(n, 2, function(v) vec[v[1]]&vec[v[2]])
which(res==TRUE)
#[1] 38
```

Comment: Thanks @ Ronak, missed a line

Comment: Thanks but this solution only works for `vec`. Isn't it?

Comment: It should work for any vec of any length containing exactly 2 ones at any positions and rest all zeros, I thought you wanted this.

Comment: containing exactly 2 ones, strong assumption. I considered this example for the purpose of simplicity.